# Swift 3 UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate not working properly

Tags: ios, swift3, delegates

I am using the shared instance of the **UIPrintInteractionController** clаss

```
let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
```

to call the Printer Options screen. I have extended my view controller with the **UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate**, but the delegate methods are called only the first time and the Printer Options screen is in full screen only the first time. Every subsequent call causes the screen to appear as a popover. I'm using the

```
present(from rect: CGRect, in view: UIView, animated: Bool, completionHandler completion: UIKit.UIPrintInteractionCompletionHandler? = nil) -> Bool
```

function, testing on an iPad Air 2.

Does anyone have an idea why the delegate methods are called only the first time?

[This is how the screen looks the first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3R7B.png)

[And this is how it looks every time I call it after the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWlwr.png)

I want it to consistently look like the first picture.

I am sorry for the bad formatting of my question. This is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow.